# Adding a play/pause toggle button to existing solution (js)

Tags: javascript

Been using the excellent solution here to make a button that randomizes some songs when clicked.

https://forums.asp.net/t/1876176.aspx?Making+a+random+sound+play+when+a+button+is+clicked

Now I realized that this can be super annoying to have it on a site, so I would like the button to be a toggle, so that you click it once and a 'random song plays', click it again 'it pauses' click it once more 'new random song plays' and that it also displays the song name some how, in plain text.

Button unclicked: 'Play Random song.'
Button clicked: 'Pause Song name 1.'

Any point in the right direction would be lovely!

```
<body>
  <input class="random_button_play" type='button' value='Try Random Sound' onclick='playRandomSound();' />
  <span id='player'></span>
<script id="jsbin-javascript">


function playRandomSound()
    {

         var sounds = [
            "song1.ogg",
            "song2.ogg",
            "song3.ogg",
         ];

         var soundFile = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
         document.getElementById("player").innerHTML="<embed src=\""+soundFile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";

    }

</script>
<style>
</style>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, if you can format properly your code will be a great help for people to help you out!

Comment: Ah so sorry, i removed a part that was there by misstake. Is it better?